# jquery jcache doesn't persist past browser refresh?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery's jCache plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jCache to cache some data that I calculate between refreshes, the problem is, after the page refreshes, the cached data seems to get lost.

```
 alert($.jCache.hasItem(window.location.href)); //false
 $.jCache.setItem(window.location.href,stringStore);
 alert($.jCache.hasItem(window.location.href)); //returns true
```

After the page refreshes, the first hasItem is false again. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used this plugin, but as I looked inside the last release from 2007! I have to say that this plugin can not store data persistent. It's somehow nothing else than a kind of stack with limited number of items to store data related to the current document.

You need to work with cookies or [webstorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) to keep data available after a refresh.

Comment: Yeah I looked at the source and it doesn't seem to store any persistent data. I'll use either cookies ajax to store the data server side or something then. Thanks :D